# Use of "and" in a list followed by "as well"

Tags: conjunctions

Do you need an *and* after *wife* in this sentence?

> The husband, wife, mother as well as the sister are coming.

Answer (score 1):

To me, that sentence sounds clunky whether you add an ‘and’ or not.

I would say one of these:

> The husband, wife, and mother are coming, as well as the sister.
>   The husband, wife, mother, and sister are all coming.

Comment: Your second example is wrong because "Both" refers to *two* people, not four.

Comment: ‘Both’ has been extended to uses with more than two elements for over six hundred years. There is no good reason to limit its use to only two elements (except dogged prescriptivism, which I don’t consider a _good_ reason), especially since there is no proper alternative for more than two elements.

Comment: And your authority for that is? [Chambers](http://http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=both&title=21st), [Oxford (ODO)](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/both?q=both), [Longmans](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/both_1), and [Webster](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/both%5B3%5D) dictionaries do not agree with you. A common and perfectly acceptable alternative is "any of".

Comment: The [OED (sense B.1.b.)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21867) has examples going back to 1405 (Chaucer) and up to 1842 (de Quincey), with quotes from both (!) Coleridge, Shakespeare, and Lydgate in between. ‘Any of’ does not work at all here—it means a completely different thing. “Any of the husband, wife, mother, and sister are coming” means that an uncertain number of people in that group are coming; with ‘both’, it means that they are *all* coming.

Comment: I can't access your link to the OED, but your comments appear to be discussing ancient - not current - usage. Yes, "Any" was wrong - I meant "All of".

Comment: It is not ancient usage—it is usage that has been well established all through the history of English (and also exists in Old Norse, where the word was borrowed from). The only reason it is not in dictionaries is that 19th-century grammarians decided it was ‘wrong’ (like split infinitives, dangling prepositions, etc.) and decried the use. It has continued to be used in the spoken language, and just like dangling prepositions, its stigma is all but gone to all but hardcore prescriptivists. “All of the husband, wife, mother, and sister are coming” sounds very odd to me, bordering on jarring.

Comment: “The husband, wife, mother, and sister are all coming” sounds perfectly natural, however.

Comment: You still have not presented any evidence for the now acceptability of _both_ being used for other than two elements. Citing accepted historic usage, and the excesses of C19th grammarians, is not sufficient. AHD and Collins are two more dictionaries not allowing the usage. Wiktionary deems it 'obsolete'.  And the fact that OED gives no examples of the usage post 1842 is a strong argument for any reasonable _descriptivist_ to label it now obsolete. We're left with the subset of prescriptivists who for some reason think that _everything_ the C19th inquisitors said must be counted as heresy.

Comment: Very well, I will remove that option and replace it with “The husband, wife, mother, and sister are all coming” instead. I still do not see how something that is heard in normal conversation on a regular basis and has established historical usage can be labelled as ‘wrong’, but I bow to the majority.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet..you are absolutely right..

Comment: It's not something I hear in normal conversation. Occasionally as an error, when people lose track of what they were saying. The sentence is much better with _all._

Comment: It's not something I've **ever** heard spoken in any register. There don't seem to be any hits on Google in the first few pages referencing other than two elements. Whereabouts do you live, JBJ, and how much do you travel? I'd reckon the usage is quite localised.